Insufficient Allowance ERC20 when adding liquidity to Uniswap V2 Pool
I am trying to create a contract with a Uniswap V2 Pair for my TestMe Token on Sepolia Testnet.
Smart Contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.24;

import "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "interfaces/uniswap-v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "uniswap-v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "uniswap-v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";

contract TestMe is ERC20, Ownable{
    IUniswapV2Pair public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
    constructor() ERC20('TestMe','TestMe COIN'){
        _mint(msg.sender, 2000000 * 10**18);
        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008); // must be exchanged for mainnet!!!
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Pair(
            IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH())
        );
    }
    
    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount) public payable onlyOwner {
        this.transferFrom(owner(), address(this), tokenAmount);
        this.approve(address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: msg.value}(owner(), tokenAmount, 0, 0, owner(), block.timestamp);
    }
}

My deploy script looks as follow:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
const fs = require("fs");

async function main() {
    let yeet; // Variable für den Yeet-Vertrag
    //0x28775000Ed20Ba9BD340e12718687F1C4A902123
    async function deploy() {
        console.log("Starting deployment script...");
        const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
        console.log("Signer fetched:", deployer.address);
      
        const TestMe = await ethers.getContractFactory("TestMe", deployer);

        const testMe = await TestMe.deploy();
        console.log("testMe contract address:", testMe.target);
        fs.writeFileSync("deployedYeetAddress.json", JSON.stringify({ address: testMe.target }));
        console.log("testMe contract address saved to deployedtestMeAddress.json");

        // Anzahl der Tokens mit Dezimalstellen
        const tokenAmountWithDecimals = ethers.parseUnits("500000", 18);
          // Aufrufen der `addLiquidity`-Funktion
        const tx = await testMe.addLiquidity(tokenAmountWithDecimals, {
            value: ethers.parseEther("0.1") // Beispiel: 1 Ether für die Liquidität
        });
        
        await tx.wait();
    }
    await deploy();

}

Generally, I am deploying a contract with 2 million tokens (18 decimals) and I would like to add 500k of the tokens to the liquidity pair (uniswap v2). I created an addliquidity function within my contract.
The contract creation works fine, but calling the addLiquidity function always returns "Insufficient Allowance".
I thought, the allowance is already be done in the transferFrom function provided by ERC20 and therefore this should work.

The error is quite clear, you'll need to approve the contract before calling a transferFrom function.
So before you call the addLiquidity function (which has the call to transferFrom), add this line.
 await testMe.approve(testMe.target,tokenAmountWithDecimals)

EDIT
Second Error:
You are passing the owner address at the place of token address.
 uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: msg.value}(owner(), tokenAmount, 0, 0, owner(), block.timestamp);

Should be
uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: msg.value}(address(this), tokenAmount, 0, 0, owner(), block.timestamp);


thank you, Approval works , you can see here https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xfb5d0f44c4bda28603f7b6bbcdf13e96121c680d
but now I receive ProviderError: execution reverted , do you have any idea why is that the case? (PS: i added your provided code just before i call the addLiq function in my deploy script)

added this in the answer @SolidityNewbie

if you are interested in accompanying me while learning, see my follow up question here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/162671/insufficient-liquidity-after-adding-liquidity-on-sepolia-uniswap-v2
