Insufficient Liquidity after adding liquidity on Sepolia Uniswap V2
I created a token "TestMe" with 2 million tokens (18dec), minting the deployer address the whole stack. I used the "addLiquidityETH" function provided by uniswap router to add 500k tokens and 0.5 ETH. When I am using the deployer wallet to place a trade via uniswap V2 app on sepolia (Buy/sell) with a small amount of token , I always receive the error message "Insufficient Liquidity".
Here is the link to the contract where you can see the AddLiquidity tx:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x6161B4E0AE26f2aB2fAC2660B73F7aaFD44FfE72
Here my code if necessary:
Deploy script:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
const fs = require("fs");

async function main() {
    
    async function deploy() {
        console.log("Starting deployment script...");
        const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
        console.log("Signer fetched:", deployer.address);
      
        const TestMe = await ethers.getContractFactory("TestMe", deployer);

        const testMe = await TestMe.deploy();
        console.log("testMe contract address:", testMe.target);

        //save address from contract
        fs.writeFileSync("deployedYeetAddress.json", JSON.stringify({ address: testMe.target }));
        console.log("testMe contract address saved to deployedtestMeAddress.json");

        await testMe.approve(testMe.target, ethers.parseUnits("500000", 18));
        await testMe.addLiquidity(ethers.parseUnits("500000", 18), {
            value: ethers.parseEther("0.1")
        });
        
    }
    await deploy();

}

contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.24;

import "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "interfaces/uniswap-v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "uniswap-v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "uniswap-v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";

contract TestMe is ERC20, Ownable{
    IUniswapV2Pair public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
    constructor() ERC20('TestMe','TestMe COIN'){
        _mint(msg.sender, 2000000 * 10**18);
        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008); // must be exchanged for mainnet!!!
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Pair(
            IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH())
        );
    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount) public payable onlyOwner {
        _transfer(owner(), address(this), tokenAmount);
        this.approve(address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: msg.value}(address(this), tokenAmount, 0, 0, owner(), block.timestamp);
    }
}


Where is the code of the attempt to trade? Is this only on the front end UI that you get that error, or is it returned from an eth call?

If I simulate I can swap eth for your token. If you only have an issue through the UI on testnets, which are rarely supported by front ends, then there may not be anything wrong with your contracts or scripts.

I only tried using uniswap front end, maybe you are right because I think 0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008 is not the official uniswap v2 router adress, i got it from stackexchange because the original for sepolia was not working - thank you i will try to perform a swap without the front end

I didn't think the front end was connected to the smart contracts on the test net. You can still use the router to test, just swap via the explorer will do a simple example for you.

An example would be great thanks, I cant seem to find your swap with the token on sepolia.etherscan tho, shouldn't it be possible to see that there?

ah nevermind, i think you interacted with 0.000001 Tokens

It was a simulation I didn't need to land it to see that it could work. Have landed it for you now to make it easy to dissect.

Thank you, if you want you could give me a small code snippet to perform a swap or anything as an answer to my question and i can mark it as the answer if this helps :)

I can't actually code this swap for you right now. But I have v2/v3 swaps in python, v2 rescue contracts in vyper. Flashbots/flashloan examples and most things defi here: https://github.com/0xMaka/w3py

Thank you, I will take a look at your answer tomorrow

Added a script, much love.

I didn't think the front end was connected to the smart contracts on the test net. You can still use the router to test, just swap via the explorer:

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xc532a74256d3db42d0bf7a0400fefdbad7694008#writeContract

Click connect to web3

Scroll to 9. swapETHForExactTokens (or 10. swapExactETHForTokens)

Enter a value to pay in eth, with the format of using a decimal point, for example 1.0 for 1

Input an amountOut (or amountOutMin), but this time no decimal, instead * 10 ** decimals the token has, for example 1000000000000000000, for 1



Try anything greater than 0 for the test.


path should be weth and your token


['0x7b79995e5f793A07Bc00c21412e50Ecae098E7f9','0x6161B4E0AE26f2aB2fAC2660B73F7aaFD44FfE72']


to should be your address or your contract, wherever the destination is.

deadline is some unix timestamp in the future.



2*10**10 is distant.


Click write

Confirm in wallet.


example swap: - https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x37c0026e736dbe4e4572f0507a5cb4a7485ca00707f70a12d515b98a95258aff

edit to add a requested example:

RPC = 'https://rpc2.sepolia.org'
CHAIN_ID = 0xaa36a7

from web3 import Web3 as w, HTTPProvider as hp
w3 = w(hp(RPC))

from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
KEY = getenv('KEY')
EOA = getenv('ADD')
#----------------------

ROUTER = '0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008'
NATIVE = '0x7b79995e5f793A07Bc00c21412e50Ecae098E7f9'
TOKEN = '0x6161B4E0AE26f2aB2fAC2660B73F7aaFD44FfE72'

ROUTER_ABI = '''
[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountADesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveB","type":"uint256"}],"name":"quote","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapETHForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]
'''

dex = w3.eth.contract(address=ROUTER, abi=ROUTER_ABI)

swap = dex.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
  # don't put value here this time that is only for explorers, put it in the transaction parameters
  0,
  ['0x7b79995e5f793A07Bc00c21412e50Ecae098E7f9','0x6161B4E0AE26f2aB2fAC2660B73F7aaFD44FfE72'],
  EOA,
  2*10**10
).build_transaction({
  'value': 1000000000000000,
  'from': EOA,
  'chainId': CHAIN_ID,
  'gas': 500000,
  'maxFeePerGas': w3.eth.gas_price * 2,
  'maxPriorityFeePerGas': w3.eth.max_priority_fee * 2,
  'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(EOA)
})

w3.eth.call(swap)

# helpers
def sign_tx(tx, key):
  sig = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction
  signed_tx = sig(tx, private_key=key)
  return signed_tx

def send_tx(signed_tx):
  w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
  tx_hash = w3.to_hex(w3.keccak(signed_tx.rawTransaction))
  return tx_hash

def main():
  ('[-] Attempting swap...')
  tx_hash = send_tx(sign_tx(swap, KEY))
  receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
  print (f'[>] Hash of attempt: {tx_hash}\n[>] {receipt}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()


The scrollscan link is not my token / contract tho, token tracker says: Cog Pool LP Token, does this make sense? Also there is no  swapTokensforETH function in the writeContract Tab for me.. sorry im new to this :D

Oh my, corrected. Much love.
